# django - how to check if model is empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have settings form page. If user filled the form once; it must display those values. But if there is no data [first time] I get query error. I need that query, because the form data must be written as related with current user [logged in].

here is my view part :

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def profile_page(request,username):
    query = Profile.objects.get(owner__username = username) ##error!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = profile_form(request.POST,instance=query)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        form = profile_form(instance=query)


    return render_to_response('profile_save.html',{'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I think I need to check the model and if it is empty I should do something different.

I am stuck.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You want to make use of the `.exists()` queryset option

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def profile_page(request,username):
    form = profile_form()
    if Profile.objects.get(owner__username = username).exists():
        query = Profile.objects.get(owner__username = username)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = profile_form(request.POST,instance=query)
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
        else:
            form = profile_form(instance=query)

    return render_to_response('profile_save.html',{'form':form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

see [QuerytSet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) for more information

Comment: i wrote into else part of the first if : form = profile_form() and form.save()

now it throws : null value in column "owner_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: you would not want to have form.save() in that else section, as you have no data in the form. Only use form.save() if you have a post and the form.is_valid()

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap that `get` query in `try ... except` and set instance to none, like this.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def profile_page(request,username):
    try:
        query = Profile.objects.get(owner__username = username)

    #to be more specific you can except ProfileObjectDoesNotExist
    except ObjectDoesNotExist: 
        query = None  #Doesn't exist, set to None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = profile_form(request.POST,instance=query)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        form = profile_form(instance=query)

    return render_to_response('profile_save.html',{'form':form},
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: you should except `ProfileDoesNotExist`

Comment: it throws global name not defined. in both situatiaon ; with Profile or not

Comment: @drTerminal add `from django.core.exceptions import  ObjectDoesNotExist`

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have use get_or_create for this purpose.

```
Profile.objects.get_or_create(owner__username = username)
```